# Get the User of an Object in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an `Article` model which is `belongs_to` a `user` so here I'm finding the user of a specific article as below:

```
article = Article.find(params[:id])
user = User.find(article.user_id)
```

As you see I achieve this via two queries, but I just want to have this in one single query. What you recommend? tnx.

Comment: Using ActiveRecord, you have to do two queries to get the two models loaded.

Comment: As Alex said, you're stuck with two queries. Only alternative I can see is writing a manual sql query, but that defeats the purpose of active record in the first place anyways.

Answer (score 2):

```
article = Article.includes(:user).where(:id => params[:id]).first
```

Comment: This returns an article object. He wants a user.

Comment: Besides, it will still run two queries.

Answer (score 1):

How about a `join`?

```
user = User.joins(:articles).where(articles: {id: params[:id]}).first
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer (if he doesn't need an article object).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry: as long as you want two objects, there is no way in Rails to select the data with one query.

You could construct a query that selects data of `Article` and `User` at the same time, store the user specific data in non DB attributes of `Article` like

```
article = Article.where(id: params[:id]).joins(:user).select('articles.title, users.name').first
puts article.attributes['name']
```

that select all data in one query, but that really spoils Rails. You won't get an `User` instance.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:-

```
article = Article.includes(:user).where("articles.id = ?",  params[:id]).first
```

now you can access user like article.user and no other query will get triggered.

> this is known as eager loading:-
>
> read more about it on rails guide.
>
> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations
>
> see also:
>
> http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading
>   http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading-revised

Comment: That will work but will still perform two queries. It's only really a benefit the other way: `user = User.includes(:articles).find(user_id)` that way it's still only two queries even if there are several articles.

Comment: This will still perform two queries.